# Conditional distribution $f(x|y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Tags: probability, distributions, independence, marginal-distribution, conditional-distribution

Suppose we have two randome variables $X$ and $Y$, with joint distribution $f(x,y)$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if the marginal distribution of $X$ is the same as the conditional distribution $f(x)=f(x|y)$.

My question is, if for some reason, the expression $f(x|y)$ does not contain the term y, does that imply $X$ and $Y$ are independent already? Without the need to compare it with $f(x)$? If it is not always correct, could someone give me a counterexample?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the conditional density does not depend on the input $y$ then that is sufficient for independence.  To see this, suppose that we can write $f(x|y) = h(x)$ for some function $h$ (i.e., as a function that does not depend on $y$).  Then we can use the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) to write the marginal density of $X$ as:

$$\begin{align}
f(x) 
&= \int \limits_{\mathscr{Y}} f(x,y) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathscr{Y}} f(x|y) f(y) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathscr{Y}} h(x) f(y) \ dy \\[6pt]
&= h(x) \int \limits_{\mathscr{Y}} f(y) \ dy \\[8pt]
&= h(x) \\[18pt]
&= f(x|y). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is a clear explanation.